# Stacked bar with JUnit style records

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have a dataset exported from a JUnitXML file and I would like to create a simple visualisation using Vega-lite of a stacked bar for each test suite. The problem is that in JUnit style you don't get a value for "success" but instead you get a "tests" fields that is the sum of all types of tests.

So far I've just naively exported as tidy data and then mapped to x, y and color.

[Current visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB6ND.png)

[Vega-editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkJelTJsUAE7JYrMXliQAvuoiQM5gNZnI7dObUbIZCV4bk1GJWozUAgXAE8oyAAzRmQxTS8jEzUoPFjCUxxDblRw9DFHZxjIAA8E9GpqS1o8AqhrVGyklLSvENYlPE7c-K8AR1Z0AeYdRipO2F14T0KlbnMMCQAvUycNFxCxNYTk1PTC4Z2NXZdtXVhkOyi9iysbR5wAbWeIA0zWyBaCwA+tZJECAAxDPL-QGPVRQPoDMwARnB1xiP0MxhhVjwINYYORUJG51x9nhkERgxwqPRGN+2K8sPxYIATMScQtyQjuP1qWBaZV6VisqTgaCWkCAMwcplkzpUlFooUxBminK4lmS6SysVwnl8pV01Ui-7UILIcxlESwkQS0wUi5yrkK3lImnK75gNWcvH2iG6truRiEfLpCmKnCs42Yv7Ov0EyVEx3QrywYOh5Dhg3usDRlWxxl6rXIIHslMkoMhsOuw04KUx72m+Ml6WByDp6tZ2u56SNn0t-06iv-TuZ7OUt38hsFptxwrmpSW622+3tsc1iNTlH95vF-2QkdeRLoRhiViWbmTutgGdegf7xOl5M5VOFE9ni9WHv8-P3vcauKT5lu2H7npeP5mJ6GKFuqAKav6MpHu+p7gd+W43n+MFzkWgEJmCw6vpWSSoV+V6Rreu7zlAi7LmINq4naT6gaREEYbmd7YQ+eGtoeRH-Ja5hrOR244H2s7cfBQGEu2gnCZBYlUbhUn4ZK5b8V4cnmCJN7if+1Eqa2SEaYUWk6bmyJKXBzJDrJ5hCdpClgHpXEAZAtFWvRq7MchUBmU50bPAAulcIAOEAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"name": "results"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": "normalize"},
    "color": {"field": "type"}
  },
  "datasets": {
    "results": [
      {"name": "test_suite_0", "type": "tests", "count": 10},
      {"name": "test_suite_1", "type": "tests", "count": 10},
      {"name": "test_suite_2", "type": "tests", "count": 10},
      {"name": "test_suite_3", "type": "tests", "count": 10},
      {"name": "test_suite_4", "type": "tests", "count": 10},
      {"name": "general-test-suite", "type": "tests", "count": 10},
      {"name": "test_suite_0", "type": "skipped", "count": 2},
      {"name": "test_suite_1", "type": "skipped", "count": 2},
      {"name": "test_suite_2", "type": "skipped", "count": 3},
      {"name": "test_suite_3", "type": "skipped", "count": 4},
      {"name": "test_suite_4", "type": "skipped", "count": 3},
      {"name": "general-test-suite", "type": "skipped", "count": 1},
      {"name": "test_suite_0", "type": "failures", "count": 3},
      {"name": "test_suite_1", "type": "failures", "count": 2},
      {"name": "test_suite_2", "type": "failures", "count": 0},
      {"name": "test_suite_3", "type": "failures", "count": 2},
      {"name": "test_suite_4", "type": "failures", "count": 3},
      {"name": "general-test-suite", "type": "failures", "count": 3},
      {"name": "test_suite_0", "type": "errors", "count": 4},
      {"name": "test_suite_1", "type": "errors", "count": 4},
      {"name": "test_suite_2", "type": "errors", "count": 4},
      {"name": "test_suite_3", "type": "errors", "count": 1},
      {"name": "test_suite_4", "type": "errors", "count": 4},
      {"name": "general-test-suite", "type": "errors", "count": 2}
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to change the tests values for success, which should be the difference of `tests-(sum of count of other fields grouped by name)` but I have no clue about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an aggregate transform followed by a calculate transform; something like this ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgO1gWwKYqgCdcBnAVwBt4TIBfAGnCnkNgxIDMB7Q7AgbSYRQEUVABWXAJZYA5rOKyE+VP3RcADgUjk+9KBym4K0bQGMuZDPEj7IsGqkjwuiCnQC6jMREgLLGgBGAJ4CmDj4HkJgDNHohlS4hNpw8GTYAHTwwRq4YAC8+WAA5PCk1MV03qLoZrAUZpTK2gBMYABUYKnpGRZW8GAAtF0IPS5utlAO2hoOJLimtExeTJDYsIQA1tqBG7aruBgW0DKyBCKikAAe5845KlAAjmRs8FKIbwBu+HaGxqZOWYkeaLaq+UKodDZXLaDBcbAyeqTSB-EywiJ0JixXypBy4ajnaKQYjkKiOMCCHxoSB9awEACMAAY7Fg8NoyiR4AB9cjvXBcxnI6EPZzlGjYny1Sx01BMlkYpwc7m8spc+lC+7ssVVaLCGnSmyy5lQVkipU8sh8rktDUwxXaiViKX9BnG8Js+2ci1WgDMtrNDrBNX1LqN8o9zHK3tVABZ-VrOeKg3raYawHKTQqoLJDkl6oMlYMVT9mJrPQTHcHUwQWuGA17iwL404SJspBpcqDddTq6ha5mI6KG5bVeq7MLtK3252dVTnTKwD66wnlSP+Tbx2WoFOOwtZ5KQwuY8vy9H+X7N3bt23d1254e00uB-XV1a45eRTuZ5WUwaGSfs1zVgKALcoizXZtr2nPcfx7P9UCfd0XzPJsP20DhYCkCgyBJfcnQfGsAKHV9R0glFMOw3DYPnNM3VNFcUI3Usr3IrCcNIPCq3gsB+yQhjGwvZiRQwtiqOTODQ0XIjzUbd8hPQij2KTbsaIIRD6KcHMMDzEDC2LMiRMojjqII1Bj2ffi11Q+SnCSQgeGU+9ezAcy+NPRsxxsqA7Iczjf0k1yNMjYcrSYu4WJ8whHIPZz6WkqMBLIyLovw5zAqzYiULk8KRWSvyJIXXigr8ID8z0iC0Nswh7KizExCiCAlloIA)):

```
{
  "data": {"name": "results"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "sum", "field": "count", "as": "total"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "count", "as": "tests"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["name"]
    },
    {"calculate": "2 * datum.tests - datum.total", "as": "passed"}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "passed"},
    "y": {"type": "nominal", "field": "name"}
  },
  "datasets": {
    "results": [
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_0", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_1", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_2", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_3", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_4", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "general-test-suite", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "test_suite_0", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "test_suite_1", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "test_suite_2", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_3", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "test_suite_4", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 1, "name": "general-test-suite", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "test_suite_0", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "test_suite_1", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 0, "name": "test_suite_2", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "test_suite_3", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "test_suite_4", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "general-test-suite", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_0", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_1", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_2", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 1, "name": "test_suite_3", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_4", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "general-test-suite", "type": "errors"}
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp, this gets me closer to what I'm after and helps me to get familiar with vega-lite, how do I add this new "passed" field to the other so I can plot the stacked bar?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the result I was after (and realised that it's not as pretty as I imagined it). I decided to pivot the columns, calculate the amount of "passed" per test suite and then fold again for easy plotting:

[Vega-editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkJelTJsUAE7JYrMXliQAvuoiQ859EtgAzbudRmAbQ0IA0JGCm48M1cAT0JTVShqc25WQnYYwMNjUwBdRMgKdDFWUxxIeFSlKKdgsFAIRqh4YvgbHTKtHVZUOjwrOzARMAAKbTweui90RhLLWDAAajBxydgAa0ZCeM0lle7e5HMU81gASjU6l3R7csIb2GRNSDrapoamqB8xZ5wAyHusEezwK01mrHmaigGy2OyhkCOJ3s+SuUBuWTwcQSzSqUVyrw0KJcGHM62i7HQ5kuLmQSkqmkYSmoZg+LgAHizIOhqMlhP1otZ-AVMfFogBHVgePDMHThbGQLyMZA-aKVVjVRzORqQTL6WKi8pKbioRnFeGK5W-KBGEyauoVbhiXws1H6zqGY2msTUz4KpUq8oihKuxTmKJ-AEPJ7mmZzKzwmHbaMFRG+ZFapqQBDFToGdxMzr-Xm0+GWEFJSyZAoxZVOgDukFyDgJEDeXV0jzsLsz8xsXb+qIMao1OAAjAAGAo2939WB4AD61kk8-H8KD0VnXbb7wd6vDYAnU5yG4Gi9Yy9Ha6xJ7n9m3jSHuLMh+tx8Dp6X-XnACYrwaoJud4Zg+u4jgek6vra75zmey4AMx-jOAxAYOoH7i+2RQQBH7nl+0iITeW7ASEaHPhBmHutQtJHMUIibiIn7yuu0FEahw77t+R5Ya4OHLquwrXuUiZwveJHsWYnGQUhMGMfOl4Cf+WabEmzyifUpE4HBXHSQusm-gp7rCdGamPnuZjSNphGwV+CEGQKykicR6niZplksdZyDzvhdlCQ5xlOaZYGjm5STUe4Yh0QMDG4UxgnQn5qkBRpYBaVJVmyfxAFxQqsYQvGJnJZJFHpTFckEeUYJxihnzOU+ODkdOJXLvpWWKZVeXVZ8gUcSFPEyaVtmte67WQgVLkpb1m4eV55VfLlo1JeNqXFeUVFKDREX0Yxs05eCC1sXVYAWWl7kZTtqanHaNXdeZk28V+8lDdEF2dTu43HSt2H9c153HGmV1dclwUnV9ukDb9SIA29h0fY1p2ld5T3lC9UMgeNRVw6F63hZFc7RZIEP-c2TT4q2IAOEAA)

```
{
  "data": {"name": "results"},
  "transform": [
    {"pivot": "type", "groupby": ["name"], "value": "count"},
    {
      "calculate": "datum.tests - (datum.failures + datum.skipped + datum.errors)",
      "as": "passed"
    },
    {
      "fold": ["passed", "failures", "skipped", "errors"],
      "as": ["type", "count"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "type": "quantitative", "field": "count"},
    "y": {"type": "nominal", "field": "name"},
    "color": {
      "type": "nominal",
      "field": "type",
      "sort": ["passed", "failures", "skipped", "errors"],
      "scale": {"range": ["green", "red", "grey", "yellow"]}
    },
    "order": {"range": ["passed", "failures", "skipped", "errors"]}
  },
  "datasets": {
    "results": [
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_0", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_1", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_2", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_3", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "test_suite_4", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 10, "name": "general-test-suite", "type": "tests"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "test_suite_0", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "test_suite_1", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "test_suite_2", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_3", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "test_suite_4", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 1, "name": "general-test-suite", "type": "skipped"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "test_suite_0", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "test_suite_1", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 0, "name": "test_suite_2", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "test_suite_3", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "test_suite_4", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 3, "name": "general-test-suite", "type": "failures"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_0", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_1", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_2", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 1, "name": "test_suite_3", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 4, "name": "test_suite_4", "type": "errors"},
      {"count": 2, "name": "general-test-suite", "type": "errors"}
    ]
  }
}
```